# Get ConnectionTimeout from Data Link Properties Dialog

Tags: c#, .net, ado

Using the below code I open the DataLinkDialog. The type ADODB._Connection has a ConnectionTimeout property and the dialog has two spots to edit a property called Connect Timeout. But these properties don't seem to correspond to each other. No matter what I change the value on the dialog to connection.ConnectionTimeout is always 15. For ODBC datasources the connect property is on the advanced tab and the all tab. In the below code i is always 15.

```
  private Connection PromptAdoEditDialog()
  {
   Connection connection = new Connection();
   connection.ConnectionString = this.AdoInfo.AdoConnectionString;
   object oADOConnection = (object)connection;
   if (this.DataLinkDialog.PromptEdit(ref oADOConnection))
   {
    int i = connection.ConnectionTimeout;
    return connection;
   }
   return null;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't ever find out how to get this information. We ended up adding text box to another window and setting that way.